# Read_csv functionality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pass to pass delimiter from the config file and my config file is something look like this i am providing the inside content of my( .config format) file and from this (.config format )file i am reading this all argument such as **path**,**delimiter**,**type of file** etc

```
path|\t|csv
path2|;|csv
```

and i am trying to fetch to data which is double quoted something look like

```
"Bhu"    "xyz"    "rax"
```

But when i am creating the data from using read_csv

```
Import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(<from config file path>,sep=<here i am putting /t from config file>)
```

But when my dataframe is created data frame is look like
'''
"Bhu""xyz""rax"
'''
But as much i know the double quotes must be remove from dataframe when i try to create the dataframe using read_csv() function but this is not happening in this case .

And it working as per my expectation when i pass separator /t as hard coding in my script like

```
df=pd.read_csv(<path from config file>,sep='/t')
```

Then its create dataframe like my expectation

```
Bhu xyz rax
```

Without any double quotes in my datafarme .but as per my understanding read_csv remove any double quotes from dataframe when it exist in source data .

So can any one help my why this is happening when i fetch delimiter from config file .i want data without double-quote in my dataframe and delimiter must be pass from config file no any hard coding in my script.

Comment: Can you provide more of your config file ? ```path|/t|csv|``` doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: Plz check the question once i have added more detailed information in config file which (.config format) and i reading this file as normal file and after split it by "|"  .

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv",quotechar='"',sep='\t')
```

quotechar option tells pandas that the data attributes are enclosed in quotation marks, in your case which is ".

UPDATE:

You can create a config file call **application.ini** and have the following as its contents

```
[FILE_CONFIG]
path = /path/to/file
sep = \t
quotechar = "
```

then the following code gives you the config as a dictionary

```
import configparser

reader = configparser.ConfigParser()

reader.read("path/to/pplication.ini")

config = dict(reader.items("FILE_FORMATS"))
```

Here `config` is the dictionary that holds all your configurations from the file.

Comment: actually my question is why read_csv() work differently. As i pass seperator from file then its behaviour is different and when i hardcode this in function directly then functionality difference in read_csv.when i pass sep by hardcoding in the script then dataframe which are formed without double quotes but when i pass using my (.config format ) file then datafarame created but inside that dataframe is in  double quotes ("xyz" ).

Comment: The separator you mentioned in your question is incorrect. It should be “\t” instead of “/t”

Comment: Also please share the format of your config file so I can answer better

Comment: Actually i already shared file format in my question and for information i am using python 3.6.3 and sorry for typo of tab (\t).

Comment: Could you add the content of the config file in the question?

Comment: You also refer my question i which i first part of my question i already mention just a part of content of my (.config) conten5